# Correct displaced columns in a table

Tags: unix, awk, sed

A bit of context: the File I've shown below is generated by a VLSI tool. It consists of timing delays caused by various components in a circuit. When I generate this "timing file" the fields are not properly organised sometimes.

The generated file:

```
something1                 0.20   0.00   0.00 
something2 6    12.95 
something3        0.00     0.08   0.00   0.00   0.07 
something4   6    8.70 
something5        0.00     0.03   0.00   0.00   0.05 
something6   5    4.70
```

What I want:

```
something1                 0.20   0.00   0.00 
something2   6    12.95 
something3        0.00     0.08   0.00   0.00   0.07 
something4   6    8.70 
something5        0.00     0.03   0.00   0.00   0.05 
something6   5    4.70
```

The displacement for   something4
and something6keep recurring throughout the table in a particular order(say every 2 lines or 1 line). Only `something2` has a different displacement whereas all the other displacements follow `something4`/`something6`.

So far I have no clue how to proceed with this. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245217/how-to-correct-displaced-columns-in-unix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correct displaced columns in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245217/how-to-correct-displaced-columns-in-unix)

Comment: And there is no header row?

Comment: and possible duplicate of [Replace empty spaces in a column with a character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52215559/3776858)

Comment: 2 of the suggested duplicates refer to an unanswered question by the same author and the third to an answered question which does not address the same problem.

Comment: Yes I posted this question again because apparently my previous question was too vague, so I wrote a new one and added some background to it.

Comment: This question and answers got @jww-ed (gratuitous downvotes for all, almost certainly from user @jww) - please upvote everything to compensate, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/ {6}/,","); gsub(/ +/,",")} 1' file | column -s, -t
something1            0.20  0.00  0.00
something2  6  12.95
something3     0.00   0.08  0.00  0.00  0.07
something4  6  8.70
something5     0.00   0.03  0.00  0.00  0.05
something6  5  4.70
```

or:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub(/ {6}/,FS); gsub(/ +/,FS); $1=$1} 1' file
something1                      0.20    0.00    0.00
something2      6       12.95
something3              0.00    0.08    0.00    0.00    0.07
something4      6       8.70
something5              0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.05
something6      5       4.70
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with awk

```
awk 'NF>3{$2=OFS$2}NF==4{$2=OFS$2}{$1=$1}1' OFS='\t' infile
```

Comment: Looks like we got @jww-ed. I'm upvoting your answer to compensate